# (Selemium/ python) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime

path = "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.bigkinds.or.kr/v2/news/index.do")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('total-search-key')
elem.send_keys('((코로나19) OR (코로나) OR (코로나 바이러스) OR (신종 코로나바이러스) OR (COVID-19) OR (코비드19))')

#ERRRRROOOOOOORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="search-begin-date"]')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('{year}-{month}-{day}'.format(year=2020, month=1, day=1))
#HEEEEELLLLLLLLPPPPPPPPPPPP

driver.find_element_by_id('방송사').click()

enter = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-search news-search-btn news-report-search-btn')
enter.click()
```

I got error in the date searching part, I thought it was because there was already text in that input box, so I cleared it with clear() but it still doesnt work. I don't know how to solve this problem... please help

under picture is that date box

[image]

Comment: Which element is represented by `//input[@id="search-begin-date"]` ?

Comment: added picture of it @cruisepandey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use explicit waits to have some stability.
2. clear is not working, not sure why, ideally it should have. so I am doing `CTRL+A` and then `delete`.
3. Launch browser in full screen mode.

**Sample code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://www.bigkinds.or.kr/v2/news/index.do")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('total-search-key')
elem.send_keys('((코로나19) OR (코로나) OR (코로나 바이러스) OR (신종 코로나바이러스) OR (COVID-19) OR (코비드19))')

#ERRRRROOOOOOORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#srch-tab1']"))).click()
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search-begin-date']")))
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
elem.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
elem.send_keys('{year}-{month}-{day}'.format(year=2020, month=1, day=1))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.ui-datepicker-trigger"))).click()
#HEEEEELLLLLLLLPPPPPPPPPPPP

#driver.find_element_by_id('방송사').click()

enter = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-search.news-search-btn.news-report-search-btn')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", enter)
enter.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```